# Firebase Custom Claims IOS and swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been reading the Firebase documents but haven't been successful in figuring out how to set custom claims in Xcode/Swift. There is no documentation for this, the only documented languages are python, Node.JS, java, Go and C#. If you know how to set custom claims in Swift, your knowledge would be very much appreciated!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Custom claims can only be set from the Admin SDKs, which are designed to be run in trusted environment such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. There is no way to set custom claims from (client-side code or otherwise) Swift code.

Answer (score 0):

read this -> [Click here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

Custom claims can only be set from the Admin SDK.